# Using OpenAI Whisper terminates immediately after running

Tags: pytorch, openai-whisper, whisper

Been searching the internet for a few days to find a fix but was unable to.

I have a fresh linux install (Arch) and fresh install of both pytorch and whisper, yet when I try to use whisper on an audio file I get an error.

`$ whisper pytorch_env/pistol.mp3 --model base`

`fish: Job 1, 'sudo whisper pytorch_env/pistol…' terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)`

Here's my list of packages if it will help:

```
certifi             2022.12.7
charset-normalizer  2.1.1
cmake               3.25.0
ffmpeg-python       0.2.0
filelock            3.9.0
future              0.18.3
idna                3.4
Jinja2              3.1.2
lit                 15.0.7
llvmlite            0.40.1
MarkupSafe          2.1.2
more-itertools      10.1.0
mpmath              1.2.1
networkx            3.0
numba               0.57.1
numpy               1.24.1
openai-whisper      20230314
Pillow              9.3.0
pip                 22.3.1
pytorch-triton-rocm 2.0.1
regex               2023.8.8
requests            2.28.1
semantic-version    2.10.0
setuptools          65.5.0
setuptools-rust     1.7.0
sympy               1.11.1
tiktoken            0.3.1
torch               2.0.1+rocm5.4.2
torchaudio          2.0.2+rocm5.4.2
torchvision         0.15.2+rocm5.4.2
tqdm                4.66.1
triton              2.0.0
typing_extensions   4.4.0
urllib3             1.26.13
```

I haven't installed anything extra, only ran the provided installation command from the pytorch site and then followed the rest of the instructions from the whisper github repository.

Importing torch and testing it shows its working so I'm kinda stuck and don't know where the problem is, since I'm pretty new to all of this.
Running `torch.cuda.is_available()` gives me true, and also using any torch functions also works withouth a problem.

Comment: Setting the correct environment variable seemed to do the job for me.
For anyone else reading this you can do it with the command export like so export `HSA_OVERRIDE_GFX_VERSION=10.3.0`